# Getting all the innerText from a <div> object

Tags: html, vba

I have a code that goes into a website, fill in a form and then get me to this webpage: http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/jurisprudencia/listarJurisprudencia.asp?s1=%28ICMS+BASE+DE+CALCULO+PIS+COFINS%29&base=baseAcordaos&url
In that page, I need the content on all these "tables". They have the following information: div class="processosJurisprudenciaAcordaos".
Inside these "tables" there are several types of information and I need them all.

Here's the code until now. ( It only goes until the webpage )

```
Sub tese()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim pesquisa As String

pesquisa = InputBox("Digite os termos que quer pesquisar: ", "", "")

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/jurisprudencia/pesquisarJurisprudencia.asp"

ieBusy ie

ie.document.getElementById("txtPesquisaLivre").innerText = pesquisa

ie.document.getElementById("pesquisar").Click

ieBusy ie


Dim elemUnique, elemCollection As Object
Set elemCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each elemUnique In elemCollection

If elemUnique.className Like "linkPagina" Then
    elemUnique.Click
    Exit For
End If
Next elemUnique
ieBusy ie




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your element to a `IHTMLElementCollection`, then loop the collection one at a time grabbing the information you need from it. In my below example, I used a msgbox to show you that you grabbed the table.

The top half of this code was used for testing purposes and to show you this is working code, the below section (under the line) is what you are needing.

Code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, Url As String
    Url = "http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/jurisprudencia/listarJurisprudencia.asp?s1=%28ICMS+BASE+DE+CALCULO+PIS+COFINS%29&base=baseAcordaos&url"

    With ie
        .navigate Url
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Visible = True
    End With

    '<------- Above was to Test, you want below this line ------->

    Dim tblColl As IHTMLElementCollection, tbl As IHTMLElement
    Set tblColl = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("processosJurisprudenciaAcordaos")

    For Each tbl In tblColl
        'Do what you need to with your table
        'Using a MsgBox to show it works
        MsgBox tbl.innerText
    Next tbl

End Sub
```